# How to tell what master page a system page is using?

Tags: master-page

I'm customizing a SP2010 site and my main pages look fine, but when I go into a site that's using the 2007 look and feel and select Site Settings or another system page, the Master Page isn't matching the branding of the rest of the site. I've tried, unsuccessfully, to track down the Master Page that is responsible.

Is there a way on the settings.aspx page to display the Master Page in use? I'm looking for a bit of code that I can insert in settings.aspx and have it display the name of the current Master Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through each master page and added a bit of HTML to determine which one was controlling the 2007 settings page in SP2010. Turns out it is `TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS/layoutsv3.master`. That's the one I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, if you click Site Actions ➪ Site Settings, and then under Look and Feel, click Master page, you should be able to change the System master page.

In SP2010, the application pages use dynamic token to refer to master page as opposed to hard wired application.master in MOSS 2007. the value of token is determined by SPWeb.MasterUrl property.